# Round Up and Round Down in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My value is 0.5503705629 and the expected value when Round up is 0.56 and Round down is 0.55.

Round down i could achieve by using

```
select round(cast( 0.5503705629 as numeric),2)::numeric(50,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Try adding a half unit to the decimal you want to round up, e.g. `0.005`

```
SELECT 
  round(0.5503705629,2) AS down,
  round(0.5503705629+.005,2) AS up;

 down |  up  
------+------
 0.55 | 0.56
(1 row)
```